# How to get url address from ASP.NET button using javascript

Tags: asp.net

I would like to get a PostBackUrl value from ASP.NET button using javascript but it seems impossible because the onclick attribute has javascript code with url address embedded.

This is what I've seen in the Chrome F12 debugger:

```
<input type="submit" name="btnGroceryShelve" value="Grocery Shelve"
 onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(
new WebForm_PostBackOptions(
&quot;btnGroceryShelve&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, 
&quot;https://www.grocerystore.com/&quot;, false, false))" 
id="btnGroceryShelve">
```

Here is asp.net code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="TestApp.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetAddress() {
            var address = $("#btnGroceryShelve").attr('onclick');
            alert("this address is " + address);
        }
        
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="GetAddress()">Get Address</button>
            <asp:Button ID="btnGroceryShelve" ClientIDMode="Static" 
runat="server" Text="Grocery Shelve" 
PostBackUrl="https://www.grocerystore.com/"/>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to extract PostBackUrl value in javascript?

Comment: Can you please post the HTML that gets rendered for that button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your `<asp:Button>` and it will have the id 'btnGroceryShelve' in your markup.